# invalid index to scalar variable seaborn.lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, google-colaboratory

I'm getting this error as I use **seaborn.lmplot** function to conditionally split the plot into facets.

[image: The output]

I'm using the built-in tips dataset.

[image: The table]

My code:

```
sns.lmplot(x='total_bill',y='tip',data=tips,col='day',row='time')
```

The thing is this happens whenever I choose splitting by the column 'day' but works fine on the others categorical columns.

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause of this error is the existence of a category containing a single datapoint. It is then impossible to fit a unique regression line. This indeed seems to be the case here:

```
tips.groupby(['day', 'time']).agg({'total_bill': 'count'})
```

Output:

```
             total_bill
day  time              
Thur Lunch           61
     Dinner           1
Fri  Lunch            7
     Dinner          12
Sat  Dinner          87
Sun  Dinner          76
```